# how to call dialog contain onclicklistener from recycler adapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to calling Dialog by clicking on the Recycle View item, but I receive an error about "Button.setOnClickListener" in my Dialog.

my `RecycleViewAdapter`

```
package com.Mypackage;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by user_adnig on 11/14/15.
 */
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static   List<DatabaseModel> dbList;
    static  Context context;
    private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;

    RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DatabaseModel> dbList, RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener ){
        this.dbList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        this.context = context;
        this.dbList = dbList;
        this.itemListener = itemListener;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itempost,parent, false);



        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(dbList.get(position).getname());
        holder.phone.setText(dbList.get(position).getphone());
        holder.adress.setText(dbList.get(position).getadress());
        holder.Emaile.setText(dbList.get(position).getTstmp());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView name,phone,adress,Emaile,id;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.edt_name_new);
            phone = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.edt_phone_new);
            adress = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.edt_adress_new);
            Emaile = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txv_Emaile_new);


            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog();

        }

    }


    public static void showDialog(){

        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(context,R.style.MaterialDialogSheet2);
        Button btnedit,btndellet;
        btnedit = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnedit);
        btndellet = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btndellet);
        btndellet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });


        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.taskopitondialog);
        dialog1.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog1.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        dialog1.show();
        dialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    }

  }
```

When I run the application receives this error

```
09-23 13:49:37.081 25068-25068/com.Mypackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.Mypackage, PID: 25068
       java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.Mypackage.RecyclerAdapter.showDialog(RecyclerAdapter.java:99)
       at com.Mypackage.RecyclerAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(RecyclerAdapter.java:86)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I delete "btndellet.setOnClickListener...." And re-run the application, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the dialog first, before you can find your buttons from your layout.

First call `setContentView()`
then call `dialog.create();`
and then you can use `findViewById()` for getting references to your buttons.